# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error in tkinter Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, syntax-error

I am trying to create a database using sqlite in python within my tkinter application - I was following a tutorial which i have used before and typed the text correctly as he had however I keep receiving an error I cannot solve - the code is below.

the error is:   c.execute("""CREATE TABLE jobdata (
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
   
  
LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35) 


conn = sqlite3.connect('jobtracker.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE jobdata (
            company text,
            role text,
            industry text,
            location text,
            wage integer,
            start_date integer,
            )""")

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

I have placed this at the top of my code above my classes I have built for my GUI - I can post the rest of the code if need be. I have gone over the syntax so many times and found it no different to how the tutorial had written it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Extra comma before `)` in the SQL statement: `..., start_date integer,)`.  Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

## Resolving the error

There's a comma following the last field in your table definition, this is likely what's causing error.

`start_date integer,` should be updated to `start_date integer`.

### Mitigating future errors

I would also recommend that you add an `IF NOT EXISTS` condition to your statement if you are going to be running the file containing this script multiple times. If you manage to create the table and then try to run a statement which would create a table with the same name you will most likely get the following error `sqlite3.OperationalError: table jobdata already exists`.

### Proposed solution #1

```py
# Your existing code as is before CREATE TABLE statement 
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobdata (
            company text,
            role text,
            industry text,
            location text,
            wage integer,
            start_date integer
            );""")
# Your existing code as is after CREATE TABLE statement
```

#### Context Managers

It may be worth considering using a context manager when performing db transactions using an `sqlite3` connection ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)).

I find them useful in terms of readability and safety, they automatically commit/rollback transactions - meaning that forgetting to run `conn.commit()` is not a concern.

Obviously there are cases in which you might not want to use a context manager, however this seems like a solid candidate for using one, just thought this worth sharing with you if you are unaware of this feature.

An example of the code from your original question using a context manager to handle the db transaction below (including changes made in direct response to question above):

### Proposed solution #2

```py
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
   
  
LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35) 


conn = sqlite3.connect('jobtracker.db')

with conn:
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobdata (
                company text,
                role text,
                industry text,
                location text,
                wage integer,
                start_date integer
                );""")
conn.close()
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer and the link to the docs helps me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are doing a mistake you are adding extra `,` at the last of

````
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE jobdata (
            company text,
            role text,
            industry text,
            location text,
            wage integer,
            start_date integer, )""")#here you are using the extra ```,```
````

The correct one

---

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE jobdata (
            company text,
            role text,
            industry text,
            location text,
            wage integer,
            start_date integer)""") #remove the coma
```

Comment: is there any major diff bw this answer and the previous answer?

Comment: Please use a valid comment inside SQL statement (`--` or `/* */`), otherwise it will raise error if OP just copy your answer and run it.